# How to display xml2json data

Tags: angularjs

I am using xml2json to translate a xml file from medline. I am stuck on using ng-repeat to display the information I need. I need to display the title,url and see-reference. When i have one health-topic in the xml file The title and url display fine. When I add more health-topics it does not work. any help is appreciated, thanks
[plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5EBRjh9w76q1cFgvmV5X?p=preview)

```
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="topic in topics">

        <td>{{topic._title}}</td>
        <td>{{topic._url}}</td>
        <td>{{topic.see-reference}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<pre>{{topics | json}}</pre>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure of your XML is like this:

```
<health-topics total="1909" date-generated="01/03/2015 02:30:35">
  <health-topic title="Abdominal Pain">
  </health-topic>
  <health-topic title="Abdominal Pain">
  </health-topic>
  <health-topic title="Abdominal Pain">
  </health-topic>
```

`xml2json` creates an object for every element. The properties of the object are the element's attributes (starting with an underscore) and the child elements. In your case:

```
//health-topics
{
  _total: "1909",
  _date-generated: "01/03/2015 02:30:35",
  health-topic: [
    {
      _title: Abdominal Pain"
    ...
```

`health-topic` is an array containing the topics. If you have a single topic wrapped with `health-topics` it would be:

```
    //health-topics
{
  _total: "1909",
  _date-generated: "01/03/2015 02:30:35",
  health-topic: {
      _title: Abdominal Pain"
    ...
```

`health-topic` is now an object. But maybe a single topic wouldn't even be wrapped with a `health-topics` element. That's something only you know.

All in all the data structure is different depending on the number of topics. You would need to check and adapt to that. The code working for multiple topics would be

```
$scope.topics = $scope.dom['health-topics']['health-topic']
```